# A question regarding Adjustment of Status while doing Consular processing

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard

I am filing for my parent's Green card. I know that there are two ways to approach this:

1. Through Adjustment of status. Where they are already in USA and I file I-130 and I-485 simultaneously.
2. Consular processing: In this case, they can stay in India and the processing will take place in India.

Now, we are going for consular processing and while filing for I-130 online, there is a question `At which USCIS office will the beneficiary apply for adjustment of status to lawful permanent resident?`

Is this question releavant for consular processing?

Comment: In the [printed version of the form](https://www.uscis.gov/i-130), questions 61a&b ask about a USCIS office if the beneficiary is in the US. Question 62a-c is to list the embassy or consulate. I assume the online form doesn't use the same numbering system?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. After looking at the form, it looks like both the options are optional. I did remove the US Consulate options since I am going for consular filing.